# excel + vba + compile error AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook (myFileNameToOpen, myFilePath) can't figure out why I'm getting this error

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm getting compile error of `Expected:=` when I run the following line of code:

`MiscFunctions.AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook (myFileNameToOpen, myFilePath)`

And here is the code for the function that is returning the error:

```
Function AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook(myFileNameToOpen As String, myFilePath As String) As String
 Dim OpenedOk, FileToOpen As String
 OpenedOk = "NOT Opened"
    If UserName = "scorekeeper" Then GoTo NothingElseTodoForscorekeeper: ' NothingElseTodoForscorekeeper
        'TempPath = Environ("userprofile")
        FileToOpen = [myFilePath] & myFileNameToOpen '' FileToOpen = TempPath & "\OneDrive\MasterFiles\" & FileNameToOpen
        'Stop  ' just for debugging

        If IsFileOpen(myFileNameToOpen) Then
        OpenedOk = "OpenedOk"
            GoTo AlreadyOpen
         Else
            Workbooks.Open filename:=myFileNameToOpen, UpdateLinks:=0
            Windows(myFileNameToOpen).Visible = False    ' hide this workbook
            OpenedOk = "OpenedOk"
        End If
NothingElseTodoForscorekeeper:
AlreadyOpen:
AutoOpenRequiredWookbook = OpenedOk
'This example names window one in the active workbook Consolidated Balance Sheet. _
'This name is then used as the index to the Windows collection.
'ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "Consolidated Balance Sheet"
'ActiveWorkbook.Windows("Consolidated Balance Sheet").ActiveSheet.Calculate

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
MiscFunctions.AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook myFileNameToOpen, myFilePath
```

The case where you want to use parenthesis around the argmuments of your function is when you are assigning the value that the function returns to a variable. i.e.:

```
x = MiscFunctions.AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook(myFileNameToOpen, myFilePath)
```

would work as well.

Comment: The reason it fails to compile is because VBA is attempting to evaluate the expression `(myFileNameToOpen, myFilePath)` and pass its result as the **first argument** of the invoked method. Removing the parentheses makes the argument list be parsed as such, rather than as an expression to be evaluated.

Comment: I must have something else wrong.  First of all thanks so much for taking time to help me with this.   `MiscFunctions.AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook myFileNameToOpen, myFilePath'

Comment: @alanBumgarner Do you get the same error as before?

Comment: no after changing the code to `MiscFunctions.AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook myFileNameToOpen, myFilePath' the error I'm now getting is `byref argument type mismatch'

Comment: I'm betting that you have already detected I'm new to stack overflow as I'm not sure if or how best to use this site to give & get info.  thanks for your patience and help

Comment: @alanBumgarner Ok, at least it's a different error. You could solve the "byref argument type mismatch" error by declaring your function as such: `Function AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook(ByVal myFileNameToOpen As String, ByVal myFilePath As String) As String`

Comment: VBA's default is to pass arguments by reference (ByRef) - [More infos](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/vb6-tip-understanding-the-importance-of-byval-and-byref-keywords/), by specifying that you want the arguments to be passed by value (ByVal), you avoid the [ByRef argument type mismatch error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byref-argument-type-mismatch) since ByVal is more lenient when it comes to the variable type of the arguments you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DecimalTurn as I included add the byref portion and that solved it. 
Function AutoOpenRequiredWorkbook(ByVal myFileNameToOpen As String, ByVal myFilePath As String) As String
 Thanks so much for your time.  I hope that I maybe able to one day return your kindness.